# Autodesk Revit 2014 .NET C# show hide window/view

Tags: c#, .net, autodesk, revit

Please advise.

I whant to show or/and hide Autodesk Revit 2014 windows views using .NET C# API.

Someone can help ?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of UI change is impossible through the API.